# Quick Launch Links hidden behind the page

Tags: sharepoint-online

The Quick Launch links in modern Team site are hidden behind the page at a certain length, It does not  show all the Link text but when you go to the Site Settings page, the link text in the quicklaunch is wrapped.

Please any solution for that problem??

Answer (score 0):

By default, quick launch will display the newly created and frequently used contents in the modern page.

As a workaround, you could create links in the quick launch manually.

1.Edit quick launch.

[image]

2.Add links.

[image]

Comment: Even manually still the same !

Comment: Whether you manually add links like the picture I added in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see when you exceed the link text limit it will not move to the next line as soon as you save it, jut shows "...."

[test1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G15Ds.png)

[image: test2e]